# pentaho spoon: how to get filename as value?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I need filename because it has information I don't have in file context.
I already have the related column in my DB.
How to get filename as a column's values?

Answer (score 0):

in your input configuration there is a section called "Additional output fields", there you must go to "Short Filename Field" and select ${Internal.Tranformation.Filename.Name}
then you cant test it on Preview Rows.

Comment: Thanks for you reply ! However it added the filename on every line. and I usually have 500000 lines in each text file, and I need to do some transformations with those files. I wonder if there's way to extract/get the filename only one time ?

Comment: you can work whit the file name using the javaScript step making use of the methods defined or define a variable whit the name of your file ..